# How to put one or many LINQ Lambda return records to List ?! C#

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

This my Code and every each line in this Action will do some stuff and retrieve some records from database , let me give a example about this Action ,this Action will display Ordre's and the products under that ordre's ,which means Ordre (1212) might have 1 one products or more than one products,But my code just show me one records for that ordre and not all of them ,so my question is how can i put return records for this action to list?! or should i do something else! Can anyone direct me in the right direction? thx

The Code in Controller :

```
public ActionResult OrdreOpenDetails(string id)
{
    DataContext data_2 = new DataContext();
    Ordre_Open_Details_VM oodvm = new Ordre_Open_Details_VM();



    oodvm.SalesLine = data_2.Sales_Line.FirstOrDefault(n => n.Document_No_ == id);
    oodvm.SalesHeader = data_2.Sales_Header.FirstOrDefault(m => m.No_ == oodvm.SalesLine.Document_No_);
    oodvm.SalesPersonPurchasers = data_2.Salesperson_Purchasers.FirstOrDefault(h=>h.Code == oodvm.SalesHeader.Salesperson_Code);
    oodvm.SalesCommentLine = data_2.Sales_Comment_Line.FirstOrDefault(z => z.No_ == oodvm.SalesLine.Document_No_);
    oodvm.PurchaseLine = data_2.Purchase_Line.FirstOrDefault(t=>t.Document_No_ == oodvm.SalesLine.Købsordrenr_);



    return View(oodvm);
}
```

My ViewModel Class :

```
  public class Ordre_Open_Details_VM
    {
        public Sales_Header SalesHeader { get; set; }
        public Sales_Line SalesLine { get; set; }
        public Purchase_Line PurchaseLine { get; set; }
        public Salesperson_Purchasers SalesPersonPurchasers { get; set; }
        public Sales_Comment_Line SalesCommentLine { get; set; }
    }
```

The Code in View:

```
@model DBhandling.Ordre_Open_Details_VM


<h2>OrdreOpenDetails</h2>

<div class="content">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-5">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-header" data-background-color="purple">
                        <h4 class="title">Detaljer</h4>
                        @*<p class="category">Detaljer <span>»</span> Order nr <span>»</span> @Model.SalesInvoiceHeader.Order_No_</p>*@
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-content">
                        <form>

                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <div class="form-group label-floating">
                                        <label>Order nr.</label>
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control border-input" disabled value="@Model.SalesHeader.No_">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <div class="form-group label-floating">
                                        <label>vare nummer</label>
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control border-input" disabled value="@Model.SalesLine.No_">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <div class="form-group label-floating">
                                        <label>Forventet levering</label>
                                        <input type="datetime" class="form-control border-input" disabled value="@Model.SalesLine.Planned_Delivery_Date">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <div class="form-group label-floating">
                                        <label>Forventet levering Direkte</label>
                                        <input type="datetime" class="form-control border-input" disabled value="@(Model.PurchaseLine != null ? Model.PurchaseLine.Planned_Receipt_Date :(DateTime?)null )">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <div class="form-group label-floating">
                                        <label>Sales Person</label>
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control border-input" disabled value="@Model.SalesPersonPurchasers.Name">
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                            </div>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-12">
                                    <div class="form-group label-floating">
                                        <label>Comment</label>
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control border-input" disabled value="@(Model.SalesCommentLine != null ? Model.SalesCommentLine.Comment : "No Comment")">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>


                            <div class="clearfix"></div>
                        </form>
                    </div>


                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you tried using `SelectMany`?

Comment: @code4life  would you please give an example with my code ! :)

Comment: I think it would be best to make your Ordre_Open_Details_VM class attributes be lists of each corresponding object. That way your instance of oodvm could be populated using the SelectMany Linq method.

In this case, the oodvm would represent multiple orders, with the index of each attribute representing a unique order entry. You could then iterate through these however you wish

Comment: Which line in the code is the actual orders?  Your view model only has individual items and would need a list of orders and then your code would need to call for the orders with a Where & a ToList.  Then you would iterate over it in your view....

Comment: @klabranche this to lines is about ordres and sir if it possible for you , it will be great give an example with my code than i can learn more about this :) -   oodvm.SalesLine = data_2.Sales_Line.FirstOrDefault(n => n.Document_No_ == id);
    oodvm.SalesHeader = data_2.Sales_Header.FirstOrDefault(m => m.No_ == oodvm.SalesLine.Document_No_);

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: I see your LINQ conditions are based on the value of the ID set in the SalesLine assignment? (`m => m.No_ == oodvm.SalesLine.Document_No_`) That's not a very smart practice, change this logic to select orders based on IDs in the data itself, not based on what you retrieved previously, otherwise the method I have described will not work. I don't know how your data is set up, so I'm just going to leave "condition" in the SelectMany function calls.

You could change your view model class to have lists of each object instead of just one instance

```
public class Ordre_Open_Details_VM
{
    public List<Sales_Header> SalesHeader { get; set; }
    public List<Sales_Line> SalesLine { get; set; }
    public List<Purchase_Line> PurchaseLine { get; set; }
    public List<Salesperson_Purchasers> SalesPersonPurchasers { get; set; }
    public List<Sales_Comment_Line> SalesCommentLine { get; set; }
}
```

Then you can utilize the SelectMany Linq method to retrieve all the orders that satisfy your conditions.

```
oodvm.SalesLine = data_2.Sales_Line.SelectMany(condition);
oodvm.SalesHeader = data_2.Sales_Header.SelectMany(conditon);
oodvm.SalesPersonPurchasers = data_2.Salesperson_Purchasers.SelectMany(condition);
oodvm.SalesCommentLine = data_2.Sales_Comment_Line.SelectMany(condtion);
oodvm.PurchaseLine = data_2.Purchase_Line.SelectMany(condition);
```

Setting it up this way, the attributes of `oodvm` would contain multiple orders, and each index would correspond to an entry.

so

```
oodvm.SalesLine[0]
oodvm.SalesHeader[0]
oodvm.SalesPersonPurchasers[0]
//...
```

would represent the first order you want. You can use this to iterate however you wish.

Comment: i changed things but i got several error : for this line **oodvm.SalesLine = data_2.Sales_Line.SelectMany(n => n.Document_No_ == id)**; and this line data_2.Sales_Header.SelectMany(m => m.No_ == oodvm.SalesLine.**Document_No_)**; and this line oodvm.SalesPersonPurchasers = data_2.Salesperson_Purchasers.SelectMany(h => h.Code == oodvm.SalesHeader.**Salesperson_Code**); and this line oodvm.SalesCommentLine = data_2.Sales_Comment_Line.SelectMany(z => z.No_ == oodvm.SalesLine.**Document_No_**);

Comment: @ManDown read my edit, you should not be retrieving your data based on what's already been retrieved, you will need to change the conditions you are using to be based on what is in your data_2 object.

Comment: All my conditions based on ID and i have to Join ID from SaleLine to SaleHeader ID ,beacuse ID in Saleheader not gonna work in SaleLine ,and this reason i did dat ,but you see my conditions would you edit on dat, so i know wat is wrong here .

Comment: @ManDown if your joins are based on IDs, then your data_2 should already be reflecting this. Use it to your advantage in your conditions.

Comment: dat wat i was trying to and i think i did it , but my problem is when i go to this ordre for ex:. ordre 1212 and this ordre have some products for ex:. keyboard , mouse , pad , but dat code i wrote ,it will show me just keyboard not mouse or pad

Comment: @ManDown your view is currently only set up to display one value, you will need to change this as well.

Comment: yes you right , but first i have to change my controller and than my view,so would you please help me with controller ,beacuse i still stuck in this

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157015/discussion-between-rh6-and-man-down).

Comment: @ManDown my work filter will not allow me to go to chat, sorry, I can't help any further, good luck with this issue.

Comment: Not Problem . tnx for your help and your time

Answer (score 0):

Your view model only has a single entity for your Orders (Sales_Line).  You need to make it a list.

```
  public class Ordre_Open_Details_VM
    {
        public Sales_Header SalesHeader { get; set; }
        public List<Sales_Line> SalesLine { get; set; }
        public Purchase_Line PurchaseLine { get; set; }
        public Salesperson_Purchasers SalesPersonPurchasers { get; set; }
        public Sales_Comment_Line SalesCommentLine { get; set; }
    }
```

Your code to populate the view model is only calling for the first item found since you are using `FirstOrDefault`.

To return many SalesLines instead use `Where` & `ToList`:

```
oodvm.SalesLine = data_2.Sales_Line.Where(n => n.Document_No_ == id).ToList();
```

Your view then will need to iterate over the list using razor syntax, something like:

```
@foreach(var saleLine in Model.SalesLine)
{
  <div>@saleLine.PropertyXYZ</div>

}
```

As a bonus you might consider changing your code to call the data to be more efficient. You are having the the database called five times with your code as is:

```
oodvm.SalesLine = data_2.Sales_Line.SelectMany(n => n.Document_No_ == id);
oodvm.SalesHeader = data_2.Sales_Header.SelectMany(m => m.No_ == oodvm.SalesLine.Document_No_);
oodvm.SalesPersonPurchasers = data_2.Salesperson_Purchasers.SelectMany(h=>h.Code == oodvm.SalesHeader.Salesperson_Code);
oodvm.SalesCommentLine = data_2.Sales_Comment_Line.SelectMany(z => z.No_ == oodvm.SalesLine.Document_No_);
oodvm.PurchaseLine = data_2.Purchase_Line.SelectMany(t=>t.Document_No_ == oodvm.SalesLine.Købsordrenr_);
```

Each line is telling EF to go back to the database in another call with constrained information from the previous call.  In this case you can create a query that actually will do this in one call.  Below is an example of taking the SalesLine call and the SalesHeader call into one database call.

```
oodvm.SalesLine = data_2.Sales_Line.FirstOrDefault(n => n.Document_No_ == id);
    oodvm.SalesHeader = data_2.Sales_Header.FirstOrDefault(m => m.No_ == oodvm.SalesLine.Document_No_);
```

Changes to:

```
oodvm.SalesLine = data_2.Sales_Line.Include(n=>n.SalesHeader).Where(n=> n.Document_No_ == id).ToList();
```

Since SalesLine is related to the SalesHeader, EF knows how to retrieve it based on the relationships defined.

The example above is using a technique called [eager loading](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/eager-loading-in-entity-framework.aspx).  I am telling EF with the `Include` operation to grab the related SalesHeader information together.  In normal SQL syntax this is like:

```
    select * from SalesLine 
    Inner Join SalesHeader on SalesHeader.Document_No_ = SalesLine.Document_No_ 
where SalesLine.Document_No_ = id
```

Entity Framework can also [lazy load](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/EntityFramework4.3/lazy-loading-with-dbcontext.aspx).  I generally shy away from lazy loading, hence my solution using eager loading.

Now `oodvm.SalesLine` will also have the SalesHeader Associated with the SalesLine and is accessed like `oodvm.SalesLine[0].SalesHeader`.

In the above case the SalesHeader will be duplicated for each SalesLine as it would in normal SQL which EF is doing on your behalf.  If you don't want duplicated information in your view model, you then have to look into using [Projection](http://www.blackwasp.co.uk/LinqProjection.aspx) in EF to transform the query results into your view model's single item of SalesHeader OR you could in your code set the SalesHeader to the first item in your SalesLines list OR you could do the same in your Razor in a header section above the loop.

Example if doing in Action:

oodvm.SalesHeader = oodvm.SalesLine[0].SalesHeader;

Example in Razor:

```
<div>
<p>Sales Header</p>
<span>@Model.SalesLine[0].SalesHeader.Property</span>
...
@foreach...
```

OR if you populated SalesHeader in the Action...

```
<div>
<p>Sales Header</p>
<span>@Model.SalesHeader.Property</span>
...
@foreach...
```

Using [projection](http://www.blackwasp.co.uk/LinqProjection.aspx) you can write one query with all of the above needed items and project it into your view model object.  It could look something like:

```
    oodvm = data_2.Sales_Line.Include(n=>n.SalesHeader)
.Where(n=> n.Document_No_ == id)
.Select(n=> new Ordre_Open_Details_VM {
      Sales_Header = n.SalesHeader.FirstOrDefault(),
      SalesLine = n
    }).ToList();
```

The above line is just illustrative of what you would do.  Lookup Projection for more guidance.

Comment: tnx for all of this , let me try :) just min

Comment: i try this two and i got red line under n => n.SalesHeader for both :             oodvm.SalesLine = data_2.Sales_Line.Include(n => n.SalesHeader).Where(n => n.Document_No_ == id).ToList();
            oodvm.SalesPersonPurchasers = data_2.Salesperson_Purchasers.FirstOrDefault(h=>h.Code == oodvm.SalesHeader.Salesperson_Code);
            oodvm.SalesCommentLine = data_2.Sales_Comment_Line.FirstOrDefault(z => z.No_ == oodvm.SalesLine.Document_No_);
            oodvm.PurchaseLine = data_2.Purchase_Line.FirstOrDefault(t=>t.Document_No_ == oodvm.SalesLine.Købsordrenr_);

Comment: and this i got error under n.SalesHeader :            oodvm = data_2.Sales_Line.Include(n => n.SalesHeader)
.Where(n => n.Document_No_ == id)
.Select(n => new Ordre_Open_Details_VM
{
    Sales_Header = n.SalesHeader.FirstOrDefault(),
    SalesLine = n
}).ToList();

Comment: If the Include line has the red line be sure to have the following using statement at the top of your controller:  using System.Data.Entity;

Comment: Troubleshooting this via comments and/or chat is not going to be easy.  My best suggestion for you is to take what I have shown as illustrative, read up on EF in general, eager loading, projection, etc....  and then create a smaller sample of the code you are using to say just load a list of orders with their sales headers.  Once you get that down, the rest you can slowly add back in.... :-)

Comment: Error is about : Cannot Convert Lambda expression  to type 'string' beacuse  it is not a delegate type

Comment: and than i got red line for this lines : oodvm.SalesCommentLine = data_2.Sales_Comment_Line.FirstOrDefault(z => z.No_ == **oodvm.SalesLine.Document_No_**);
            oodvm.PurchaseLine = data_2.Purchase_Line.FirstOrDefault(t => t.Document_No_ == **oodvm.SalesLine.Købsordrenr_**); | and error for both : SalesLine does not contain a definition for 'Documnet_No' and Købsordrenr_